# Obtain Date value from HTML form and pass it in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, server

I'm trying to get a date from an HTML form into PHP, to then pass it to a MYSQL database. In PHP I get the date with a POST method.

```
$Data = $_POST['Data']; //Data
```

In HTML i made up this:

```
<input type="date" name="Data" id="Data" required/>
```

When I try to send it to my database with the mysqli_query() method, I always get this error:

> Incorrect date value: '' for column 'Data' at row 1

Can you please help me?

This is the query if you are interested. All the other variables work.

```
INSERT INTO 'table_name' ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', Data, 'col5', 'col6')

VALUES ('$var1', '$var2', '$var3', '$Data', '$var5', '$var6')";
```

EDIT: (Whole Form)

```
    <form action="insert.php">
        <div class="banner">
          <h1>Prenota pasti al Podere Diamante</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>Nome</p>
          <div class="name-item">
            <input type="text" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>Numero Telefonico</p>
          <input type="text" name="NTelefonico" placeholder="### ### ####" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>Data di prenotazione</p>
          <input type="date" name="Data" id="Data" required/>
          <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </div>
   <div class="item">
          <p>Orario di prenotazione</p>
          <input type="time" name="NGruppo" required min="19:00" max="21:30" step="1800"/>
               </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>Con quante persone sarai?</p>
          <input type="number" name="NPersone" min="1" max="150" required/>
        </div>
         <div class="item">
          <p>Note aggiuntive</p>
          <textarea rows="3" name="Note"></textarea>
        </div>
         <div class="btn-block">
          <button type="submit" href="/">Invia</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Compare data type of the field and the value you are trying to tinsert.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Data` column in MySQL. You must be getting a string from the form. Convert it to the correct before inserting into MySQL

Comment: Is there a way to do it? I was trying to print the $_POST[] result, but i obtained a blank page.

Comment: just use `var_dump($Data);`. See table structure in MySQL to see the type of Data field.

Comment: @Ash1271 its type is DATE. I tried to convert the string from the form to date with PHP methods such as strtotime(), but nothing happened.

Comment: @Ash1271 thanks for the help. I obtained "NULL" as result of the method. How is it possible?

Comment: Just try `var_dump($_POST)` and see the result. If it is also null, post the full HTML of the form.

Comment: First make sure the $Data variable gets it value correctly from the POST call. Is the SQL calls in a different file from the html form or does the html form post to itself?

Comment: The SQL calls are in the PHP file, wich is the "action" of the form. Im now posting all the HTML form as you said

Comment: Just posted it, @Ash1271

Comment: Check the `date format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<form action="insert.php">
```

to

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
```

The default HTTP method of a form is `GET`. You must specify `POST` since you are accessing it using `$_POST`. Then you should be able to get the value of the `Data` field in `$Data`.

If it doesn't fix the errors, try the following:
1 Check the datatype of `Data` column in your MySQL table, and make sure that your `$Data` is in correct format.

For example: If your `Data` column is a `DATE` column, `$Data` should be in `YYYY-mm-dd` format.

Other Date - Time types and format is given [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-data-types.aspx):

```
Date and Time Types                          Description
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 DATE                         A date value in CCYY-MM-DD format
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 TIME                           A time value in hh:mm:ss format
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 DATETIME     A date and time value inCCYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 TIMESTAMP      A timestamp value in CCYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 YEAR                         A year value in CCYY or YY format
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

> Extra Read: Methods GET and POST in HTML forms - what's the difference?http://jkorpela.fi/forms/methods.html

Comment: Really useful. Thank you @Ash1271, i'll check the read.

Answer (score 0):

In the database you need to set the date field to  type date and in the input field of the form you need to capture the correct date format.  Or alternatively use a date picker field

```
        <label><strong>Date </strong> </label></div>
              <input type="date" name="date">
```

Comment: <div class="item">
          <p>Data di prenotazione</p>
          <input type="date" name="Data" id="Data" required/>
          <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you need the current date just you the built-in date in php

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
```

Else check your sql date column and make sure it's Varchar then do this

```
<form action="insert.php" 
method="post">
//in your insert try using
'".$Data."' in place of '$Data'
```